# Terraform how to force AWS ASG to create new instances when lauch config is updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

When I update the launch config of an AWS ASG, the ASG is updated but the existing running instances are not recreated with the new launch config.

How can I tell ASG to recreate instances?

This is my current terraform config:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "app-lc" {
  image_id             = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type        = "m4.large"
  security_groups      = ["${split(",", var.security_groups)}"]
  user_data            = "${file("user_data.sh")}"
  key_name             = "${var.key_name}"

  root_block_device {
    volume_type           = "standard"
    volume_size           = "50"
    delete_on_termination = "true"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "app-asg" {
  name                      = "my-asg"
  max_size                  = "${var.asg_size}"
  min_size                  = "${var.asg_size}"
  desired_capacity          = "${var.asg_size}"
  launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.app-lc.name}"
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  health_check_grace_period = "600"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${split(",", var.server_subnets)}"]
}
```